# Announcing an election for July 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Expression Engine Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/election/3) on **June 19** to bring in one more moderator.

The timeline:

Starting on July 12, the Community Team will post a question collection post on Meta. In it, community members can submit questions they'd like to see the nominees answer.

Starting on July 19, users can [nominate themselves](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/election/3). At that point, the questions from the above post will be collected into a questionnaire, so nominees can post their answers alongside their nominations.

On July 26, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), but I doubt that will come up.)

If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 3 (or August 10, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.